# Need an example of groovy-wslite POST with multiple parameters

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to make a secure POST to https://example.com/api/login with parameters Username and Password.  I'm trying to use the wslite plugin with Grails, but I can't figure out the syntax.  I've checked the unit tests at github, but none of them have given me what I need.  Maybe I'm just failing to connect the dots.

Anyway, does anyone have an example of multiple parameters to a POST?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following example to post your request.

```
def client = new RESTClient("https://example.com/api/login")
// for testing only!
client.httpClient.sslTrustAllCerts = true

def response = client.post() {
    charset "UTF-8"
    urlenc username: "test", password: "test" // here you can provide your params as a map
}
```